# To pick null values also as part of xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am reading an XML File named extract.BCBR.job.xml and extracting values through xmlstarlet looking for %%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME and getting its value ,while it works well , what I want to achieve is to also extract the null values in cases when the element %%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME is not present ,so that the output file /tmp/prcsname_2 returns also all null values , ultimately I am looping over this file with a "for" loop over 700 times , so I would also need null Values in my iteration for some "if" and "else" conditions , could you please guide me in extracting the null values also and if there's anything in xmlstarlet for the same :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB[@APPL_TYPE="PS8"]/VARIABLE[@NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME"]' -v './@VALUE' -n ~testhwa/extract.BCBR.job.xml >> /tmp/prcsname_2
```

Sample Input :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- XML Utils Details: version 9.0.0. Exported at 20210503-130101 by rfernan9 from server DEV -->
<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">
    <FOLDER DATACENTER="DEV" FOLDER_NAME="DVFINAL" LAST_UPLOAD="20101206223355UTC" PLATFORM="UNIX" REAL_FOLDER_ID="0" TYPE="1" USED_BY_CODE="0" VERSION="919">
<JOB
            APPLICATION="DVPeopleSoft_Finance"
            APPL_FORM="PEOPLESOFT"
            APPL_TYPE="PS8"
            APPL_VER="8"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="0"
            CM_VER="6.1.01"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="prichar3"
            CREATION_DATE="20101206"
            CREATION_TIME="163137"
            CREATION_USER="prichar3"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYSCAL="02/05/2009"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="origtasktype=Command, &quot;Daily Close GL Reports &quot;"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="T"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="3"
            JOBNAME="PFD_GLR01DLY_PF_RPTBOOK-01A"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="0"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="0"
            MAY="1"
            MEMNAME="PFD_GLR01DLY_PF_RPTBOOK-01A"
            MULTY_AGENT="N"
            NODEID="FS90QAT1"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            PARENT_FOLDER="DVPeopleSoft_Finance"
            RETRO="0"
            RUN_AS="CONTROLM"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SHIFTNUM="+00"
            SUB_APPLICATION="PFD_GLR01DLY"
            SYSDB="0"
            TASKTYPE="Dummy"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
            WEEKSCAL="03/05/2009">
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="start_FS90QAT#PFD_GLR01DLY-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="FS90QAT#PFD_GLR01DLY_PF_RPTBOOK-01A-OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-CON_PROFILE" VALUE="QAT"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-USERID" VALUE="CONTROLM"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-RUNCONTROLID" VALUE="GLR01DLY1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PRCSTYPE" VALUE="nVision-ReportBook"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PRCSNAME" VALUE="RPTBK01"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-APOUT" VALUE="1"/>
        </JOB>

<JOB
            APPLICATION="DVPeopleSoft_Finance"
            APPL_FORM="PEOPLESOFT"
            APPL_TYPE="PS8"
            APPL_VER="8"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="0"
            CM_VER="6.1.01"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="stamilar"
            CREATION_DATE="20131106"
            CREATION_TIME="110438"
            CREATION_USER="stamilar"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            DAYS="ALL"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="origtasktype=Command, &quot;Pcard paycycle USA&quot;"
            FEB="1"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="1"
            JOBNAME="PFD_SP01DLY_AP_PF_PC_USA"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="0"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="0"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="Not in use for PeopleSoft jobs"
            MEMNAME="PFD_SP01DLY_AP_PF_PC_USA"
            MULTY_AGENT="N"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            PARENT_FOLDER="DVPeopleSoft_Finance_AP"
            RETRO="0"
            RUN_AS="BATCH"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SHIFTNUM="+00"
            SUB_APPLICATION="PFD_SP01DLY_AP_PF"
            SYSDB="0"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMEFROM="1900"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
            WEEKDAYS="ALL">
            <OUTCOND NAME="PFD_SP01DLY_AP_PF_PC_USA-OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-CON_PROFILE" VALUE="FS90QAT"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-USERID" VALUE="BATCH"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-RUNCONTROLID" VALUE="PC_USA"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-SERVERNAME" VALUE="PSUNX"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PRCSTYPE" VALUE="PSJob"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-APOUT" VALUE="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-OUTDESTFORMAT" VALUE="HTM"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-OUTDESTTYPE" VALUE="Web"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-JOBNAME" VALUE="APPCJOB"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-DESCRIPTION" VALUE="PayCycle Job"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P1-DESCRIPTION" VALUE="PayCycle Job"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P1-PROCESSNAME" VALUE="APPCJOB"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P1-PROCESSTYPE" VALUE="PSJob"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-DESCRIPTION" VALUE="Pay Cycle Process"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME" VALUE="AP_APY2015"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSTYPE" VALUE="Application Engine"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P3-DESCRIPTION" VALUE="Pay Cycle Job Finalize"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P3-PROCESSNAME" VALUE="ZPV_FINALIZE"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P3-PROCESSTYPE" VALUE="Application Engine"/>
        </JOB>
```

Sample Output :

```
<Blank Line>
AP_APY2015
```

Regards,
Sriram.V

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, Added Sample inputs and Outputs

Comment: With two roots (`JOB`) it's no valid XML.

Comment: Hi @cyrus, The XML is too huge to paste here , I have simply extracted some Stanzas from it , the root is DEFTABLE. Check now , have edited the input to put in the root and how its in the original file.

Comment: There is no such thing as a null value in the XML data model, and since the XML you have shown us isn't even well-formed, I have to give up: I've tried, but I simply don't understand your question. The problem is, if you don't understand the basic terminology of XML, it's very hard to ask questions that make sense, so you really need to do some reading.

Comment: Hello @Michael Kay, The XML is formatted well, it is a huge one , which is why I haven't pasted it completely here,..I have been getting xmlstarlet outputs through my script without issues..as I am iterating through a for loop over this XML File ,some of the JOB tags donot have the element  %%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME , so the output file does not consider the output to be NULL in that iteration, but it only redirects output when there is not null value , how do we tweak the xmlstarlet query to also fetch null values , I did do a lot of reading on XMLStarlet, but I did not find option.

Comment: Well, you won't find the XMLStarlet documentation says anything about null values, because there is no such thing in XML. To use its documentation effectively, you will need to learn the correct XML terminology. To solve the problem of the input file being vast, I suggest you abstract the essentials of the problem into a new question that makes your point using a much smaller and simpler XML file with the same essential characteristics: most of the XML you're asking us to wade through is completely irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I think you mean

While respectfully acknowledging the remarks from (the great) Michael Kay and Cyrus, I'm guessing you're thinking about XML from a database perspective.

Extending that assumption, and looking at both input and output samples, I'd rephrase your question to:

1. Print the value from the `VALUE`-attribute, if the `<VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME" VALUE="AP_APY2015"/>` node exists as a child from `<JOB/>`
2. Print a 'null value' (newline), when `<JOB/>` has no such `<VARIABLE/>` child *(with the particular `%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME`-value in the `NAME`-attribute)*.

Basically then, you'd be asking to transform your XML to something like CSV.
In that case you'd be much better helped with (learning) XSLT, but that's not the topic at hand nor the solution you want.

###### Simplified input

Remarks:

- Please do include closing tags
- Using `xmlstarlet fo ~testhwa/extract.BCBR.job.xml` helps formatting your input XML, which makes it easier for others to help you
- I can imagine others from your organization might not be too happy seeing data from internal systems being publicly visible on the internet, even if it's just two lines, even if it's just a testing environment - so I'd suggest leaving out everything that's not strictly necessary for your question (even my simplified input sample is probably too verbose)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DEFTABLE>
  <FOLDER>
    <JOB APPL_TYPE="PS8">
      <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="start_FS90QAT#PFD_GLR01DLY-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
      <OUTCOND NAME="FS90QAT#PFD_GLR01DLY_PF_RPTBOOK-01A-OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB APPL_TYPE="PS8">
      <OUTCOND NAME="PFD_SP01DLY_AP_PF_PC_USA-OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
      <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME" VALUE="AP_APY2015"/>
      <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSTYPE" VALUE="Application Engine"/>
      <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P3-DESCRIPTION" VALUE="Pay Cycle Job Finalize"/>
      <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P3-PROCESSNAME" VALUE="ZPV_FINALIZE"/>
      <VARIABLE NAME="%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P3-PROCESSTYPE" VALUE="Application Engine"/>
    </JOB>
  </FOLDER>
</DEFTABLE>
```

##### `xmlstarlet` example

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/DEFTABLE/FOLDER/JOB[@APPL_TYPE='PS8']" --if "VARIABLE[@NAME='%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME']" -v
 "VARIABLE[@NAME='%%PS8-PROCESSES-J1-P2-PROCESSNAME']/@VALUE" --else -o "" -n ~testhwa/extract.BCBR.job.xml >> /tmp/prcsname_2
```

###### `xmlstarlet` example explained:

- `--if` takes an XPath as argument. The `--if` tests whether the (matched) `<JOB/>` has a childnode `<VARIABLE/>` with the given @NAME-attribute. If it does, it prints out the @VALUE for that childnode (as you already did in your `xmlstarlet`-example)
- (no `--elif` in this case)
- `--else` handles the situations in which there is no such `<VARIABLE/>` childnode. It then uses the `-o` (output) option, that has an empty string as an argument. You might even leave out that `-o`, but the `-o` makes it a little more verbose, for others to see what you mean.

###### Output

```
AP_APY2015
```

#### Additional thoughts

Database tables act like storage closets with drawers. There might be something in the drawer, or the drawer could be empty. An empty drawer would have a 'NULL' value in it.
In XML, no empty drawers exist. Therefore, XML doesn't allow for NULLs.

Put differently, database table definitions specify a fixed number of columns. For each row in the table, a column is filled or not. An empty column translates to 'NULL'.
XML on the other hand defines a new 'row definition' if you will, for each new 'row'. The number of 'columns' (child nodes) may differ per 'row'. Like in your sample input, where the first `<JOB/>` contains less `<VARIABLE/>` childnodes. A 'NULL' in a database table means, there's no childnode in XML. At all. Note that an 'empty string' in a database column would translate to an XML-element without any childnodes.

In this case, `xmlstarlet` didn't need the `--break` argument, to 'escape' from the if-else-branching. In case you'd need extra if-tests, on different paths, you might need to use `--break` to stop the previous if-else-branching.

All in all, even though `xmlstarlet` is capable enough of handling questions like these, I would strongly suggest considering XSLT for this task. There might be a steep learning curve, but eventually you'll probably be much better off.  `xmlstarlet` queries will get cumbersome and long very quickly. XSLT gives you much greater control. It will make your scripting much more flexible: instead of having to use tool-specific arguments, you'll apply a powerful, versatile, flexible (Turing-complete) transformation language. It might make your tooling maintainable by others than yourself (which is a plus in any organization). You'll find plenty of samples on XSLT-related topics on StackOverflow. Heck, you may even find one of the authors of the original specifications replying to your questions (he already did here ).